# I am trying to install postgres.app on my Mac but it won't work

Tags: macos, installation, terminal, sql, postgresql

I am currently trying to set up Postgres.app on my Mac running 10.14 Mojave. When reading the guide online, it says to open terminal and use the command:

```
sudo mkdir -p /etc/paths.d && echo /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin | sudo tee /etc/paths.d/postgresapp
```

When I do this I am asked for a password like so:

```
John-MBP:~ MyName$ sudo mkdir -p /etc/paths.d && echo /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin | sudo tee /etc/paths.d/postgresapp
Password:
```

But for the love of me **I cannot figure out what the password is**. I also **cannot use my keyboard to type anything**, only the enter key works. If you know what to do to fix this, your help would be greatly appreciated.

This is my first post on here, so I hope this is line with the rules, if not could you please tell me where to look for help.

Comment: You can just type the password here. The page shows it to us as asterisks. Like, `********`.

Comment: I mean, just to make sure the password isn't revoked yet. If it is, it won't show as asterisks, but that's because is revoked.

Comment: Thank you both for responding,  but the problem is that I literally cannot type a password on the terminal. It gives me the prompt "Password: " but I cannot type any letters or numbers or anything. I can hit enter but when I do that it says "Sorry wrong password".